# Eclipse update changed theme color

Tags: eclipse

Basically, I updated my eclipse from Mars.1 to Mars.2, and in doing so the default theme changed from white to light purple. Personally, I hate this color and can't find a way to revert it back to white. Deleting my ui prefs configuration does not work, reverting using the preferences menu does not work, etc. The only option I'm down to is a complete re-install, however I would rather not do that if there's another way I don't know about.

It currently looks like this

[image: Eclipse with purple theme]

It should look more like this

[image: Eclipse with white theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparrently this purple theme replaced the other theme in Eclipse Mars.2, cannot revert to the whiter one.

Answer (score 1):

One thing depends here is how you updated your eclipse.

Here, you can scene your eclipse. Follow steps and look around.

1) Goto `Windows` Menu --> `Preference`.

2) Choose `General` --> `Appearance`

3) Theme --> `Windows Classic` and Color and Font theme: `Default`.

[image]

Comment: That does make it white, however it loses it's appearance. The theme that it had was exactly the same as the picture I posted above, however the purple tint was colored white.

Comment: don't you have any other options in theme? This is the only preference in eclipse to change the color and theme. your windows theme may alson matters in case of native theme.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that the style was permanently changed in Mars.2, not positive though